# Translating SQL into relational algebra

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, relational, relational-algebra

I'm just learning how to translate sql queries to relational algebra and the other way around.

```
Customer(customer_name, customer_street, customer_city)
Loan(loan_number, branch_name, amount)
Borrower(customer_name, loan_number)
Account(account_number, branch_name, balance)
Depositor(customer_name, account_number)
```

I want to find customers who live in Fairfax, have a loan, but DO NOT have a bank account.

```
CustomersInFFX = PROJECT customer_name (SELECT customer_city = 'Fairfax'(Customer))
LoanOwners = (CustomersInFFX NATURAL JOIN Borrower NATURAL JOIN Loan)
AccountHolders = (Depositor NATURAL JOIN ACCOUNT)
PROJECT customer_name (LoanOwners - AccountHolders)
```

Does this make sense?

*SELECT: σ, PROJECT: π, NATURAL JOIN: ⋈

Comment: does not make much sense to me.. do you want to ask somethink more concrete? i don't see any sql to be translated to or from and even if i don't know anything about relational algebra, i don't think the `customer_name = 'Fairfax'` would find you customers who live there..

Comment: Selection (σ) is used currectly. You dont need to see the sql queries to figure out rational algebra. It should be evident from the description

Comment: haha i meant customer_city. My bad...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt using standard SQL:

```
WITH CustomersInFFX 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT *
        FROM Customer
       WHERE customer_city = 'Fairfax'
     ),
     LoanOwners 
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM CustomersInFFX 
             NATURAL JOIN Borrower 
             NATURAL JOIN Loan
     ),
     AccountHolders
     AS
     (
      SELECT *
        FROM Depositor 
             NATURAL JOIN ACCOUNT
     )
SELECT *
  FROM LoanOwners
EXCEPT CORRESPONDING DISTINCT
SELECT *
  FROM AccountHolders;
```

However, this will only work if the `LoanOwners` and `AccountHolders` tables have the same number of attributes each with the same name. This is unlikely to be the case, therefore you will need to project (`SELECT`) only the required attributes e.g.

```
SELECT customer_name
  FROM LoanOwners
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT customer_name
  FROM AccountHolders;
```